# Список возвращаемых полей bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Есть ли документация по тому, какие поля возвращает функция, например GetIBlockElementList

Answer (score 0):

Документация, безусловно есть.
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/functions/getiblockelementlist.php
К сожалению качество документации оставляет желать лучшего. В узких кругах состояние документации является известной шуткой.

Самый лучший вариант иметь под рукой актуальные файлы ядра и пользоваться подсказками IDE.